# PHP: Adding multiple associative arrays to another array

Tags: php, arrays

Here's a sample of data

```
Date  | Source | Amount
-----------------------
01A   | S1     | 12
01A   | S4     | 2
01A   | S7     | 134
02A   | S1     | 126
03A   | S4     | 10
02A   | S7     | 0
02A   | S1     | 3
02A   | S4     | 4
02A   | S7     | 5
```

The resulting array needs to look like:

```
Array
(
    [01A] => Array
        (
            [S1] => 12
            [S4] => 2
            [S7] => 134
        )
    [02A] => Array
        (
            [S1] => 126
            [S4] => 10
            [S7] => 0
        )
    [03A] => Array
        (
            [S1] => 3
            [S4] => 4
            [S7] => 5
        )
)
```

I've tried looking at pages such as [PHP Adding multiple associative arrays to new array based on key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979310/php-adding-multiple-associative-arrays-to-new-array-based-on-key), [PHP multiple arrays to one associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179374/php-multiple-arrays-to-one-associative-array) and [Merge multiple associative arrays to a single array of associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873951/merge-multiple-associative-arrays-to-a-single-array-of-associative-arrays) and playing around with code as below (not using the same data - but same theory) but it's not producing what I need. The code below just shows A and B

```
    $array = Array();
    $a=array( "ABC" => array("A"=>"RED","B"=>"GREEN"));
    $b=array( "ABC" => array("C"=>"BLUE","D"=>"YELLOW"));
    $array = $a + $b;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Is the original data in a database? If so which one?

Comment: Yes - it's a cut down version of MySQL

Comment: There are a lot of PHP [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) you can use. Or use a simple [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop to build the expected array. Have you tried anything?

Comment: That's why I am asking for - I'm not sure how to do it - I've tried

Comment: Then you should look up how to Pivot a Table [Here would be a good start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) Then you can get MYSQL to do all the work for you

Comment: It's very cut down.... like only SELECT and WHERE allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KISS

```
$result = array();
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    if(!isset($result[$row['Date']])) $result[$row['Date']] = array();
    $result[$row['Date']][$row['Source']] = $row['Amount'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the data in the `$input` array, the code is as easy as:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($input as $row) {
    $date = $row['Date'];
    if (! array_key_exists($date, $result)) {
        $result[$date] = array();
    }

    $result[$date][$row['Source']] = $row['Amount'];
}
```

If you don't have the data in `$input` but you fetch it from the database just replace the line:

```
foreach ($input as $row) {
```

with something that matches your data retrieval loop, f.e.:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```